# Updating Image in Yii2

Tags: yii2

While updating image using Yii2 I'm facing a problem with the validation.Its always asking me to upload an image. But I don't want this. Always updating an image is not necessary.

I tried `skipOnEmpty` but its not working properly it cause effect while uploading a photo, which is also incorrect.

Please help!!

Model

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['carid', 'name'], 'required'],
            [['carid', 'coverphoto', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
            [['imageFiles'], 'image','extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg, gif', 'maxFiles' => 4, 'minWidth' => 100, 'maxWidth' => 800, 'minHeight' => 100, 'maxHeight'=>600,'skipOnEmpty' => true],


        ];
    }
```

Controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->photoid]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should to use `scenario` for update.

Like as,
Add `on` condition in model's rule for applying `scenario` .

```
 [['imageFiles'], 'image','extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg, gif', 'maxFiles' => 4, 'minWidth' => 100, 'maxWidth' => 800, 'minHeight' => 100, 'maxHeight'=>600,'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'on' => 'update-photo-upload'],
```

And use that `scenario` in controller's action.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->scenario = 'update-photo-upload';
    ........
    .....
}
```

Comment: @GAMITG thanks it really helped, had wasted 8 hours to find a solution and felt helpless before arriving at this answer

Answer (score 0):

try rule as

```
[
    ['imageFiles'], 'file',
    'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg, gif', 
    'mimeTypes' => 'image/jpeg, image/png',
    'maxFiles' => 4, 
    'minWidth' => 100, 
    'maxWidth' => 800, 
    'minHeight' => 100, 
    'maxHeight'=>600,
    'skipOnEmpty' => true
],
```

This is working in my case, hope it works for you too.

Comment: I tried. But validation for create(upload an image) is not working now. 
I want image validation for create only but not for update. @ankitraturi

Answer (score 0):

```
        **Your View Like This**

        <?php use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;?>
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles')->fileInput() ?>
        <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
         </div>
        <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>

    *** Your Controller Like This******

    use Yii;
    use yii\web\Controller;
    use app\models\UploadForm;
    use yii\web\UploadedFile;

    class SiteController extends Controller
    {
        public function actionUpdate()
        {
            $model = new UploadForm ();
            $model->scenario = 'update';
            if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
                $model->imageFiles= UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFiles');
                if ($model->upload()) {
                    // file is uploaded successfully
                    return;
                }
            }

            return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }

 ***** Your ModelLike This ******

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile[]
     */
    public $imageFiles;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
             [['carid', 'name'], 'required'],
             [['carid', 'coverphoto', 'status'], 'integer'],
             [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
             [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4,'on'=>'update'],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) { 
            foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
                $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

function scenario()
{
    return [
        'create' => ['imageFiles ', 'carid','name','coverphoto','status'],
        'update' => ['imageFiles ', 'carid','name','coverphoto','status'],
    ];
  }
}
```