# Yii2 conditional validation for image file upload

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am very new to Yii.

I have to apply image validation (.svg and .png allowed) only if user have selected the image.

```
  public function rules() {
        return [
            [['logo'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'svg, png'],
        ];
    }
```

When user select image it works fine.
But on update form we have only name of file. Now if we submit the form it will apply validation. I need validation only if user changes the image.

My Controller code

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->logo = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'logo');
            if (!empty($model->logo)) {
                $model->logo->name = $model->logo->baseName . Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp(date('Y-d-m h:i:s')) . '.' . $model->logo->extension;
                $logoPath = Yii::getAlias('@common') . '/web/uploads/logo/' . $model->logo->name;
                $model->logo->saveAs($logoPath, false);
            }
            if ($model->updateSite()) {
                return $this->redirect(['site-list']);
            }
        }
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification.
Thanks.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920022/updating-image-in-yii2/32921854#32921854

Answer (score 2):

Using scenarios may be helpful in this case.

Define validation rules to dependend on scenario

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['logo'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'svg, png', 'on' => 'imageUploaded'],
    ];
}
```

Then define scenario for model in controller. Something like this.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->logo = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'logo');
        if (!empty($model->logo)) {
           $model->scenario = 'imageUploaded';
           ...
        }
    }
```

It's also possible to define anonymous function for conditional validation.

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['logo'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'svg, png', 'when' => function ($model) {
             //return true to apply the rule
             return $model->isImageUploaded();
        }],
    ];
}
```

More on rules and scenarios can be found here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-validation.md#declaring-rules-